# Jackson & Spring MVC: dynamically filter child objects of an object

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson

I have use  spring MVC, jackson and hibernate in the past, no I have to build a rest backend and Im thinking about sticking with the same technology.

two things I haven't been able to do in the past is cut how deep jackson serialize objects. for example lets say I have two classes:

```
public class Person{
    public int id;
    public String name;
    List<Role> roles;

}


public class Role{
    public int id;
    public String roleName;

}
```

So what I want to do with jackson and spring mvc is dynamically decide when serialize a Person whether to give the List of roles with the full serialize object or just the object id, for example:

```
{id:1, name:"jhon", roles:[{id:1, roleName:"admin"},{id:2, roleName:"user"}]}
```

OR dynamically choose to give just the ids of the roles and not the full object

```
{id:1, name:"jhon", roles:[{id:1},{id:2}]}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this with jackson filters and Spring mvc? I have done some research but Im not sure where to go, can you please point me to the right direction? :)

Thanks!!

Comment: Out of curiosity, Why would you like to do like this ?

Comment: Im also using hibernate, so when I return an object jackson also publish all the childs of the object (I end up with all DB publish), so I want dynamically to publish the the whole object child or just de childs ID so the clients know how to ask for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use I wrote called [Squiggly Filter](https://github.com/bohnman/squiggly-filter-jackson).

This library will allow you to dynamically filter properties based on a query string parameter.

In your case, you can select only the ids of the roles by doing the following on the query string:

```
/people/1?fields=**,roles{id}
```